# How To Stop Servlet Redirect From Html

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I Want To Send Data From Html Web Page to My Server Using Servlet.

```
<form method="post" name="customerForum" action="addCustomer">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="addCustomerBTN"
         type="submit" value="addCustomer">Add Customer
 </button>
</form>
```

This Is My Servlet Class

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/addCustomer")
public class PSystemServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String customerID = req.getParameter("custID");
        String customerName = req.getParameter("custName");
        
    } 
}
```

If I Press The Button WebPage Redirect To My Servlet Class (using this urlPatterns = "/addCustomer").
But I Need to Send Data From the HTML webpage To My Servlet Class But I Do Not Need to Redirect To Servlet Class.

How Can I Stop Redirect Servlet Class and Send My Data To Servlet Class Without Redirecting..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Jumping into the solution,You should know AJAX,How it works

Try This:
Client Side:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <body>
        <form method="post" name="customerForum">
            CID:  <input type="text" id="custID" name="custID">
            CNAME:<input type="text" id="custName" name="custName">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="addCustomerBTN"
                    type="button" value="addCustomer" onclick="register()">Add Customer
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>

        function register()
        {

            var custName = document.getElementById('custID').value;
            var custID = document.getElementById('custName').value;
         
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "addCustomer",
                data: {custID: custID, custName: custName},
                success: function (status) {
                    
                    alert(status);//You can add if codition to check status values and alert msg accordingly if 'inserted' then alert data inserted sucessfully
                }
            });



        }

    </script>

</html>
```

Server Side(addCustomer Servlet):

```
        String status="notInserted";
        String customerID = request.getParameter("custID");
        String customerName = request.getParameter("custName");
        System.out.println("custID:" + customerID);
        
        //Your insert Logic
        
        //if data inserted sucessfully  set status="inserted";
            status="inserted";
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(status);
```